# how to read array elements from user in python

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to read array elements as

```
4 #no. of elements to be read in array
1 2 3 4
```

what i have tried by referring other answers

```
def main():

    n=int(input("how many number you want to enter:"))
    l=[]
    for i in range(n):
        l.append(int(input()))
```

this works fine if i give input as

```
4 #no. of elements to be read
1
2
3
4
```

but if i try to give like

```
4 #no. of element to be read

1 2 3 4
```

I get error as:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 2 3 4'
```

Please help me with this

Comment: I take it you mean that when you enter a string such as '1 2 3 4' as your input, the error is raised. This is because Python can't convert a string with non int characters in it, into an int. You need to split the text (`.split()`) would work and use the resultant array.

Comment: It's not clear *why* you want to ask the user for the number of inputs when the user is going to give you that number of inputs anyway. Seems redundant. On the other hand, if it were to check the input validity, I imagine you'd want to check other aspects too, like that the inputs are in fact numbers (for that see [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](/q/23294658/4518341)).

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no input delimiters in Python, you should use [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and split the input that you've received from the user:

```
lst = your_input.split()
```

Comment: moreover, this makes the for loop redundant - but would be best to specify to the user that the numbers should be delimited by spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Your first approach is OK, for the second way use this:

```
n=int(input("how many number you want to enter:"))
l=map(int, input().split())[:n] # l is now a list of at most n integers
```

This will [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) the function [`int`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) on the split parts (what [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) gives) of the user input (which are `1`, `2`, `3` and `4` in your example.

It also uses slicing (the `[:n]` after `map`) to slice in case the user put more integers in.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = input("how many number you want to enter :")

l=readerinput.split(" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `input()` function returns a string that the user enters. The `int()` function expects to convert a number as a string to the corresponding number value. So `int('3')` will return 3. But when you type in a string like `1 2 3 4` the function `int()` does not know how to convert that.

You can either follow your first example:

```
    n = int(input('How many do you want to read?'))
    alist = [] 

    for i in range(n):
        x = int(input('-->'))
        alist.append(x)
```

The above requires you to only enter a number at a time.

Another way of doing it is just to split the string.

```
    x = input('Enter a bunch of numbers separated by a space:')
    alist = [int(i) for i in x.split()]
```

The `split()` method returns a list of numbers as strings excluding the spaces